# Query to get Hierarchical data and its level number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have One Table with following field in Oracle 10G Database

```
GOAL_ID
PARENT_GOAL_ID
GOAL_NAME
```

and data like

```
GOAL_ID PARENT_GOAL_ID   GOAL_NAME
1          null           GoalX
2            1            GoalY
3            1            GoalZ
4            3            GoalN
```

I need a query which will give the result by prepending the level to GOAL_NAME like following

```
1     GoalX
1.1   GoalY
1.2   GoalZ
1.2.1 GoalN
```

Number of child nodes can go to any extend. So the query should be able to get its level number

Comment: Belongs to [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com) like does this similar [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39400/get-hierarchial-data-in-self-referencing-table-parents-childs)

Comment: You might be right @AlexPoole, its said to be dedicated to `Database Administrators`. I thought R Khan would find help there.

Comment: Can you add more sample data and results to clarify how the ‘level’ string should be generated? And explain it in words too?

Answer (score 2):

## Ahhh, Recursion!

For each row, the query needs to trace up (or should I say down) the family tree until it reaches a Null parent_goal_id (the ultimate parent / the root node) and build up a node id by dot-deliminating the goal_id's along the way regardless of how many levels there may be.  Recursion is the answer.

We can do it with straight SQL using a CTE which, uncharacteristically for SQL, is almost elegant :). This does the trick (I tested it, results below):

```
WITH a (node, goal_id, parent_goal_id, goal_name) AS 
    (SELECT cast(goal_id AS varchar) + '' + cast('' AS varchar) AS node, *
        FROM tbl
        WHERE parent_goal_id IS NULL  --ultimate parent
        UNION ALL
        SELECT cast(a.node AS varchar) + '.' + cast(b.goal_id AS varchar) AS node, b.*
        FROM tbl b
        JOIN a ON b.parent_goal_id = a.goal_id
    )
SELECT * FROM a
```

Results - I added some more rows for the test:

```
node       goal_id  parent_goal_id  goal_name
1          1        NULL            goalx
1.2        2        1               goaly
1.3        3        1               goalz
1.3.4      4        3               goaln
1.3.8      8        3               goald
1.3.4.6    6        4               goalb
1.3.4.6.7  7        6               goalc
1.2.5      5        2               goala
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry..I need it in Oracle

Comment: I'm running SQL Server so I can't test it but I think this is still close.  Did you get an "column alias list" error or something else?

Comment: @RKhan -  I'm running SQL Server so I can't test it but I think this is still close. Did you get an "column alias list" error or something else?

Comment: #UPDATED FOR ORACLE#  @RKhan , I updated the query to include an explicit column list for Oracle.  See if that takes care of it.

Comment: For Oracle you need to give a size when casting to varchar (and should be varchar2 really); and the concatenation operator is `||` rather than `+`. (And we’ve interpreted the question differently; only the OP can tell us which of us has got the right result though *8-)

Comment: And recusion isn’t avaialble in 10g sadly, it was added in 11gR2; so neither of our answers will help the OP!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BCEJGIBG) (from 11gR2) to work through the hierarchy and build up the ‘level’ label/string as you go, using analytic queries to figure out the position in the current level each time round the loop:

```
with rcte (root_id, label, goal_level, goal_id, goal_name) as (
  select goal_id,
    to_char(row_number() over (order by goal_id)),
    1,
    goal_id,
    goal_name
  from goals
  where parent_goal_id is null
  union all
  select r.root_id,
    r.label ||'.'|| row_number()
      over (partition by r.root_id, r.goal_level order by g.goal_id),
    r.goal_level + 1,
    g.goal_id,
    g.goal_name
  from rcte r
  join goals g
  on g.parent_goal_id = r.goal_id
)
select label, goal_name
from rcte
order by root_id, goal_level, goal_id;
```

The anchor member gets the root IDs - those without parents - and assigns them as level 1 in the hierarchy, while numbering them sequentially via an analytic function.

The recursive member then finds the children, increasing the level, and concatenating the sequential number within the parent’s children to the label string.

Recursion continues until there are no more children.

Demo with your sample data, and some extras, in a normal CTE:

```
with goals (GOAL_ID, PARENT_GOAL_ID, GOAL_NAME) as (
  select 1, null, 'GoalX' from dual
  union all select 2, 1, 'GoalY' from dual
  union all select 3, 1, 'GoalZ' from dual
  union all select 4, 3, 'GoalN' from dual
  union all select 5, null, 'GoalA' from dual
  union all select 6, 5, 'GoalB' from dual
  union all select 7, 6, 'GoalC' from dual
  union all select 8, 6, 'GoalD' from dual
)
, rcte (root_id, label, goal_level, goal_id, goal_name) as (
  select goal_id,
    to_char(row_number() over (order by goal_id)),
    1,
    goal_id,
    goal_name
  from goals
  where parent_goal_id is null
  union all
  select r.root_id,
    r.label ||'.'|| row_number()
      over (partition by r.root_id, r.goal_level order by g.goal_id),
    r.goal_level + 1,
    g.goal_id,
    g.goal_name
  from rcte r
  join goals g
  on g.parent_goal_id = r.goal_id
)
select label, goal_name
from rcte
order by root_id, goal_level, goal_id;
```

which gets:

```
LABEL   GOAL_NAME
------- ---------
1       GoalX
1.1     GoalY
1.2     GoalZ
1.2.1   GoalN
2       GoalA
2.1     GoalB
2.1.1   GoalC
2.1.2   GoalD
```

Comment: Oh... just noticed 10g mentioned in the question body (but not tags). So this type of recursion isn’t available to the OP sadly. I’ll leave this as it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is to use `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`:

```
SQL> with test (goal_id, parent_goal_id, goal_name) as
  2  (select 1, null, 'goalx' from dual union
  3   select 2, 1, 'goaly' from dual union
  4   select 3, 1, 'goalz' from dual union
  5   select 4, 3, 'goaln' from dual
  6  )
  7  select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(level, '.'), '.') scbp,
  8         goal_name
  9  from test
 10  connect by prior goal_id = parent_goal_id
 11  start with parent_goal_id is null;

SCBP       GOAL_
---------- -----
1          goalx
1.2        goaly
1.2        goalz
1.2.3      goaln

SQL>
```

I know, SCBP doesn't really reflect your desired output, but - that's what you get with LEVEL pseudocolumn. Hopefully, someone else will provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you're on 10g you can't yet use recursive subquery factoring (see previous answer), so you're stuck with [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html). @Littlefoot has already shown this approach, but using the hierachical level numbers which doesn't seem to be quite what you want based on the limited sample data.

You can use a regular (non-recursive) CTE to assign a nominal ranking to each row in your original table based on the current parentage, and then perform the hierarchical query against that CTE, using those generated rankings to build up the 'label' string:

```
with cte as (
  select goal_id, parent_goal_id, goal_name,
    row_number() over (partition by parent_goal_id order by goal_id) as rn
  from goals
)
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(rn, '.'), '.') as label,
  goal_name
from cte
start with parent_goal_id is null
connect by parent_goal_id = prior goal_id;
```

Demo with your sample data, and some extras, in a normal CTE:

```
with goals (GOAL_ID, PARENT_GOAL_ID, GOAL_NAME) as (
  select 1, null, 'GoalX' from dual
  union all select 2, 1, 'GoalY' from dual
  union all select 3, 1, 'GoalZ' from dual
  union all select 4, 3, 'GoalN' from dual
  union all select 5, null, 'GoalA' from dual
  union all select 6, 5, 'GoalB' from dual
  union all select 7, 6, 'GoalC' from dual
  union all select 8, 6, 'GoalD' from dual
),
cte as (
  select goal_id, parent_goal_id, goal_name,
    row_number() over (partition by parent_goal_id order by goal_id) as rn
  from goals
)
select ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(rn, '.'), '.') as label,
  goal_name
from cte
start with parent_goal_id is null
connect by parent_goal_id = prior goal_id;
```

which gets

```
LABEL                GOAL_
-------------------- -----
1                    GoalX
1.1                  GoalY
1.2                  GoalZ
1.2.1                GoalN
2                    GoalA
2.1                  GoalB
2.1.1                GoalC
2.1.2                GoalD
```